# Render a Javascript page in swift without Webview

Tags: javascript, swift

SO after some research, I found out that you can execute Javascript code through `context.evaluateScript`, here is my current code:

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://cdn.azureradio.com/invocation/clearwater/iOS/the_beat.html") {
    do {
        let contents = try String(contentsOf: url)
        print(contents)
        let context = JSContext()!
        let value = context.evaluateScript(contents)
        do {
            sleep(4)
            print(value!.toString()!)
        }
    } catch {
        // contents could not be loaded
    }
} else {
    // the URL was bad!
}
```

However, my output is just `undefined`. The Javascript is supposed to generate a HTML page and I will soup it, however the javascript will not run on swift. You can look at https://cdn.azureradio.com/invocation/clearwater/iOS/the_beat.html

You can view my log here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRDfL.jpg
If anyone knows how to generate a html page form JS please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You create a JSContext out of nowhere and expect that it will render something in the screen whereever you intend?

It's impossible to render HTML without a webview. Even NSAttributedString creates a webview under the hood to render html.

Comment: So there is no way to render this if the device is locked / in the background?